# Representing carriage returns and quotes with regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to replace a carriage return followed by quotation marks with just quotation marks.  For example, if I have:

```
Hello World
"Hello World"
```

I would like the result to be:

```
Hello World"Hello World"
```

This is my attempt, where String text is what I have above:

```
String adjusted = text.replaceAll("[\n][\"], "\"");
```

However, my IDE does not accept this.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` to avoid matching regular expression, but instead matching literals.

```
String adjusted = text.replace("\n\"", "\"");
```

If you want this method to use you operating system line separators you should use

```
String adjusted = text.replace(System.lineSeparator()+"\"", "\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String adjusted = text.replaceAll("(?m)\r?\n\"", "\"");
```

The `(?m)` is for multi-line usage, for `\r` for a real CR in Windows (CR+LF).

Comment: Correct, except you don't need the `(?m)` modifier.  It only changes the behavior of the anchors (`^` and `$`), which he's not using.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in a platform agnostic way like:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String newStr = str.replaceAll(newline, "\"");
```